# Scraping makes the divs change dynamically

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the data inside the table.
The problem is that when I'm scrolling down the website, few divs are getting deleted, while others getting added so I can't get the data.
I need to get almost the who columns(trying to move this table as is to dataframe using selenium, can't download the file).
What's wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

# options.add_argument("--headless")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\Program Files                        (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
stealth(driver,
    languages=["en-US", "en"],
    vendor="Google Inc.",
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
    renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
    fix_hairline=True,
    )



url = "https://data.gov.il/dataset/personal_import_vehicles/resource/03adc637-b6fe-402b-9937-7c3d3afc9140"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
src = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").get_attribute("src")
driver.get(src)
#test=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='slick-cell l0 r0']");
#test3=driver.find_elements_byxpath("//div[@class='slick-cell l4 r4']");
start=1
end=10
id_=[]
name=[]
while(end<200):
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("from").clear()
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("from")
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    element.send_keys(str(start))
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "to")))
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("to").clear()
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("to")
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    element.send_keys(str(end))
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    try:
        result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slick-cell l0 r0']")))
        result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='slick-cell l0 r0']")
        for i in range(len(result)):
            print(result[i].text)
    except:
        pass
    start+=10
    end+=10
    time.sleep(1)}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
654
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
11
12
654
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
6826
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
163
164
165
166
167
168
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and some deprecation warnings..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use selenium they broadcast everything directly from a json api.

```py
from json import dumps
from requests import post

def get_all(limit = 0): return post(
    url = 'https://data.gov.il/api/3/action/datastore_search', 
    headers = {
    },
    json = {
        "resource_id":"03adc637-b6fe-402b-9937-7c3d3afc9140",
        "filters":{},
        "include_total":True,
        "send_analytics_event":False,
        "limit": 1 if limit == 1 else get_all(1).json()['result']['total'],
        "offset":0,
    },
)

x = get_all().json()['result']['records']

print(dumps(x, indent=2))

# you will get alot of results
print(len(x))
```

Comment: yes I know but I don't want to use the api(or download the csv)

Comment: When you use selenium then selenium will just use the API with the javascript run in the website. so you can not get around using the API. You just let the browser do the job for you and waste alot of energy and time when you do it with selenium.

Comment: Not using API is part of the project.  After filling the input labels I'm getting exposed to new rows in the table, and by crawling I save them to list(of the rows). After that I can continue with my ML project, anyway It works now... thanks anyway.
Still Im not sure Im using the api while crawling the website, so I would like to get a better explantion. thanks again.

Comment: It makes no sense - why would you use a front end testing tool to do web crawling. It is taking way too many resources, and you expose yourself to many unnecessary side effects. On top of that you could just use selenium to find the api link and then get the data. But of course if the project is about learning how to make things as hard as possible for yourself, then you are on the right path. Happy holidays.